# How can I access to internal VPC http endpoint from Google Cloud Scheduler?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I would like to know if it is possible to execute a job to make a post to an internal VPC http endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

At this time we cannot make a post directly to an internal VPC endpoint. However, depending on your VPC set up, you could set up a gateway (not recommended) or set up a VPC connector. For a VPC connector you'll need an additional service such as a Cloud Function to create the connection in which you would forward the scheduler request. Learn more about [connecting to a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc).